# How get LTE cell info on android API 16 and lower?

Tags: android, lte

I need get cell id, lac (or respectives) to LTE cell. I know that is easy on API version 17 and higher, but I really need get this on the older versions.

So, someone could help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't, normally you would get cellinfo using the following objects and their methods:

CellInfoGsm <---- Anything other than LTE

CellInfoLte <----  LTE only

As per the android docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfoLte.html

CellInfoLte was added in api 17.  Which makes sense considering nearly every lte device now runs on api 17 and they want you to upgrade not downgrade.

If this is because you have an old device that doesn't support 17 and somehow supports lte (very extreme case but I am sure there probably is such a phone) you'll have to wait for a KitKat droid build, since that is designed to run on older devices as well as the new ones.

Comment: Thank you, I'll repass to my boss. Hugs!

Comment: I made a research today and I can to say that is possible. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8782183