# Getting RSSI in wcdma and lte and ec/io in wcdma

Tags: android, rssi, lte

I want to get rssi value in wcdma and lte not RSCP or RSRP values.

When I used `getCellSignalStrength()` method for lte ,it returns RSRP value.

When I used `getsignalStrength()` method for wcdma, it returns asu value and I used  this formula `2*asu-113` for getting RSCP value.

However, I can not reach rssi value both lte and wcdma.In addition, I can not take ec/io value. But, when I used `*#0011# code` ( opens Samsung servis mode) , I can see more detail information about wcdma and lte (rssi,ec/io,rsrq,tx,rrc end etc).

How do I get these information in android programmability?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618167/get-signalstrength-without-using-phonestatelistener-onsignalstrengthchanged

Comment: Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754879/gsm-rssi-and-lte-rssi-and-rsrp or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545026/how-to-get-lte-signal-strength-in-android

Comment: Thank you for reply but I tried all referred methods. Hovewer, I can not take real RSSİ value for both LTE and WCDMA networks. These methos give either Rsrp or rscp value, not give rssi value. RSSİ value is different from each other.It contains noise and interference. I need to get the RSSI value or I have to get **ec/io** for WCDMA and **sinr** for LTE.@Gaston

Comment: Here is something from Qualcomm that might help: https://source.codeaurora.org/external/gigabyte/ag-gb-dsds-7227/plain/frameworks/base/telephony/java/android/telephony/SignalStrength.java